# dynamically loading images in expression engine with jQuery and p+t matrix

Tags: jquery, expressionengine

I'm trying to figure out how to use jquery to dynamically load slides in a matrix field each time a button is clicked.

I have this matrix field that can have any number of images in it. there are a small but variable number of entries (about 5), each with different slideshow content in their matrix field.

One option is that I could create a separate template that just outputs the matrix field, and then selectively pull in < li >'s by id with .load

$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');

but this template will only be good for the most recent entry, and will give the others the wrong slides.

The other way I thought to do it is to use jquery to dynamically update the matrix parameters. but, I can't seem to write EE tags in js which are then parsed:

$('ul#slides').html("{project_images limit='2' offset='0'}{/project_images}");

this just renders static html.

I feel like maybe there is some way of doing this, maybe using the (javascript template?) that I don't know about.

My best clue is this brief thread from brandon kelly: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/method_to_limit_matrix_results_for_slideshow

But I'm not sure what to do next...

Does anyone have thoughts for how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: not certain I understand the question, but it seems you need a tag inside here:  $('ul#slides').html("{project_images limit='2' offset='0'}{some_field_or_other}{/project_images}");

Answer (score 5):

The comment above is important; make sure you actually have stuff inside your `{project_images}{/project_images}` tag pair.

Also check your configuration -- either under **Admin -> Security -> Output and Debugging**, or in your config file if you prefer to use file-based configuration -- and make sure that `Debugging` is set to `1` (Show error messages to Superadmins only), **not** to `0` (Don't ever show error messages). Setting to 0 causes weird issues with EE tags inside Javascript, and always has.

Answer (score 4):

Your plan to load the additional content using jQuery .load(), loading additional matrix content as an html fragment will work.

To make sure you load matrix data for the correct entry you can pass the entry_id as a url segment.

So:

Create a template group called "ajax.group" and add a template called "matrix.html" (these names are arbitrary). Then when you load the matrix data you would do so like

```
$('#result').load('/ajax/matrix/{entry_id} #container');
```

Make sure you put this jQuery in a place in your template where {entry_id} will be parsed and supplied with the currently viewed entry id. Alternatively you could use url_title or a segment based variable containing the entry_id or url_title.

Then, in the ajax/matrix template you'd do something like

```
<div id="container">
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name_here" entry_id="{segment_3}"}
    {matrix_custom_field_name offset="1"}
        {matrix_column_short_name_here}
    {/matrix_custom_field_name}
{/exp:channel:entries}  
</div>
```